# Is there a command something like \NeedsTeXFormatAtLeast{LaTeX2e}[date]

Tags: preamble, latex-base

I know about the command `\NeedsTeXFormat`, as in such as `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]`. But:

- does this automatically allow a later LaTeX format to be used?
- if not, is there some similar command to specify to use a LaTeX format *at least* as new as the specified date?

Comment: yes of course any later date is accepted

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: thanks for the edit. I was looking for something appropriate, which your edit gives as `latex-base`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any format released after the specified date is accepted. An earlier release date issues a warning.

Consider the file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\showthe\fmtversion
\stop
```

No problem at all and I get

```
> \fmtversion=macro:
->2023-11-01.
```

Let's fake being after the next release, which will be dated `2024-05-31` (or thereabout):

```
\def\fmtversion{2024/05/31}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\show\fmtversion
\stop
```

No problem at all and I get

```
> \fmtversion=macro:
->2024/05/31.
```

Note that `\NeedsTeXFormat` will look at the meaning of `\fmtversion` and nothing else. Indeed if I fake having an earlier release

```
\def\fmtversion{2023/05/31}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\show\fmtversion
\stop
```

the LaTeX run issues

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2023/11/01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2023/05/31' is available.

> \fmtversion=macro:
->2023/05/31.
```